# How can I get rails to serve up videos properly using send_file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, video-streaming, passenger

It's a project requirement that some assets not be publicly accessible, so I'm serving them up through an AssetsController, like this:

```
  def show
    asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
    unless Article.viewable_by(current_user).find_by_id(asset.attachable_id).nil?
      send_file asset.data.path(style = params[:style]), :type => asset.data_content_type, :disposition => 'inline' #THIS
    else
      head(:forbidden) and return
    end
  end
```

Works fine for images. Videos aren't playing in the browser. They work fine when served up from /public.

Here are some screenshots (pulling the assets, network tab on Chrome developer tools is open)

**Working** (it plays, still seeing canceled requests)

[image]

**Broken**

[image: Broken]

Here's what Apache has to say about it:

```
[ pid=2796 thr=140722427586528 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:784 time=2011-12-06 21:36:57.803 ]: Either the vistor clicked on the 'Stop' button in the web browser, or the visitor's connection has stalled and couldn't receive the data that Apache is sending to it. A$
```

I made two requests, and got several of these for each one.

Any ideas?